# Call Ant target directly and indirectly based on condition

Tags: ant

I have the following default target defined in my build file:

```
<target name="main" depends="generate.doc" unless="generated.doc.present"/>
```

The property is set when the doc files already exist. In that case I don't want to do anything. However, it doesn't work since the dependent target is always executed before the condition is evaluated.

I still need to be able to call the dependent target directly and execute it, no matter if the output already exists or not. Hence something like this would not work:

```
<target name="main" depends="generate.doc"/>
<target name="generate.doc" unless="generated.doc.present">...</target>
```

Is there a solution without using `antcall` in the main target?

Comment: How is the `generated.doc.present` property set? Is it set inside or outside of Ant? If it's set inside of Ant, is it set inside or outside of a `<target>`?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the description of the problem. Are you saying that when you call `main` you only want the document to be generated if it doesn't already exist, but when you directly call `generate.doc` you want it to be generated no matter what?

Comment: @Chad Nouis, the property is set with `<available file="${generatedRoot}" type="dir" property="generated.doc.present"/>` in the same build file and outside of `<target>`.

Comment: @CAustin, that's exactly what I want. We often just call `ant` in our project and some other tasks are performed as well, like compiling source code. The build file for the doc generation is included and just calling `ant` should then also generate the doc if it's not already present. However, we also need to be able to call `ant generate.doc` on our project to regenerate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example below, the `main` `<target>` has been changed to have two dependencies. A new `<target>` named `-pre-conditions` will run before `generate.doc`.

The `-pre-conditions` `<target>` sets the `skip-generate.doc` property only if the `generated.doc.present` property has already been set.

The `generate.doc` `<target>` has been changed so it will be skipped if `-pre-conditions` set the `skip-generate.doc` property.

With these changes, `generate.doc` will always run when it's called directly.

```xml
<target name="-pre-conditions">
    <condition property="skip-generate.doc">
        <isset property="generated.doc.present"/>
    </condition>
</target>

<target name="main" depends="-pre-conditions, generate.doc"/>

<target name="generate.doc" unless="skip-generate.doc">
    <echo>generate.doc running</echo>
</target>
```